# How to use PHP to control on or off of light and air conditioner?

Tags: php, hardware, controls

Is it possible even to do this kind of things?

**EDIT**

Can someone provide a "hello world" demo to try out?

Comment: Obv. this is a silly comment but in one of my computer science classes my freshman year we used java to program and control lego mindstorms (lego robotics).  I would assume you could program other hardware with java but I am unsure about PHP.

Comment: I've never done things like control hardware with software,and don't know where to start at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

X10/Insteon are good bets. I have seen that both of them have developer kits. You have to at least but some modules for the appliances/outlets you wish to control. I would stay away from the AC unit and just buy a programmable thermostat ;) In the end, you're going to have to do research and buy some interface hardware and control modules. X10/Insteon is probably the cheapest way to get to you goal.

Begin rant:
I have personally used X10 and it was pretty easy to use, simple serial port/com port interface to trigger lights. I don't have the code anymore, besides I feel like you're looking for a copy-n-paste solution without thinking about the problem. Even if there is an API in Java/C/C++/Python/etc... you can find a way to invoke it from PHP. Asking a more specific question may get a more specific answer. Also, don't ask for a language you admit that you don't know.

Answer (score 1):

[X10 java api](http://www.micheldalal.com/sw/java/x10/). And [another](http://www.agaveblue.org/projects/x10/).

[SmartHome](http://www.smarthome.com/) - everything related to home automation.

Comment: Is there a PHP version?In fact I'm not so familiar with JAVA.

Comment: And I'm not that familiar with PHP :-) Seeing as how C / C++ / Java APIs exist I'm sure one can be written for PHP if noone has done it already.

Comment: Have you ever tried X10?Do I need to buy some hardware for it to work?

Comment: What are you going to control if you don't have any hardware? First link I posted provides java API for FireCracker X10 controller kit, you can expand from there.

Answer (score 1):

Most if not all digital I/O cards for PCs are controlled through an interface written in C.  Then most of *those* offer a library so you can control the boards through software you've written.  Since you are able to make extensions for both of those languages in C, you could indeed write a Java or PHP wrapper around a C library for a digital I/O card and control pretty much anything that *can* be controlled with a digital signal.

For instance, Google quickly turned up the [HW-Group IO Controller](http://www.hw-group.com/products/io_controller/index_en.html) with libraries in Java and PHP (among others) and with 8 in, 8 out DIO.

Comment: That's the theory,anything practical?

Comment: PHP communicating with a phone to send out sms and so on. how about that? customized DLL extension written in C working with the GSM modem drivers.

Comment: Many industrial applications - this is pretty much the only way to do data acquisition of multiple signals at a very high sampling rate, on a PC.  Although robots usually use embedded devices, there's no reason you couldn't have a full-fledged computer with some sort of DIO board controlling it.  I think some CNCs fall into this pattern as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is. Google X10 - a protocol for cumunicating with things like lights and appliances.

Answer (score 0):

X10 devices can be used for example to control Lava Lamps for extreme feedback when doing continuous integration. There is plenty of literature on this subject on the net. Have a look at the [X10 CM17A API](http://www.micheldalal.com/sw/java/x10/) and [Bubble, Bubble, Build's In Trouble](http://pragmaticautomation.com/cgi-bin/pragauto.cgi/Monitor/Devices/BubbleBubbleBuildsInTrouble.rdoc) for a real world use case.